# Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, circuit

Please help me! Tor gets as far as establishing a circuit, then fails. It says:

```
Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.

Establishing a Tor circuit failed (connection timeout - 161.53.160.104:9090).
```

This s what the log looks like:

```
2/16/2016 8:35:13 AM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/16/2016 8:35:14 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
2/16/2016 8:35:14 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
2/16/2016 8:36:42 AM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
2/16/2016 8:37:59 AM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 6DFEB41C04CCE846871338E85DD5ACF5CFB6C1DD at 192.42.115.102:9004) 
2/16/2016 8:37:59 AM.400 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
2/16/2016 8:37:59 AM.400 [WARN]  7 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/16/2016 8:37:59 AM.400 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/16/2016 8:38:21 AM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 11; recommendation warn; host C80EAE6D0B1FB69785002829E02DCC3E35539A60 at 192.241.180.163:9001) 
2/16/2016 8:38:21 AM.400 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
2/16/2016 8:38:21 AM.400 [WARN]  8 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
2/16/2016 8:38:21 AM.400 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
```

Comment: This fail may be that the network you resides in is censored or constrained due to your proxy or router that hosts your connection. Do you try to use "Configure" instead of "Connect" directly when you first executed the Tor Network Settings ? Good luck :)